# Print the 5th letter of each word read from a text file

Tags: c, file-io

I wanted to find the 5th letter from every word after reading from the text file. I do not know where I am wrong.

After entering the file path, I am getting a pop up window reading

> `read.c` has stopped working.

The code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main(void){
  char fname[30];
  char ch[]={'\0'};
  int i=0;
  FILE *fp;
  printf("enter file name with path\n");
  gets(fname);
  fp=fopen(fname,"r");
  if(fp==0)
       printf("file doesnot exist\n");
  else{
       printf("File read successfully\n");
       do{
         ch[i]=getc(fp);
         if(feof(fp)){
             printf("end of file");
             break;
         }
         else if(ch[i]=='\n'){
             putc(ch[4],stdout);
        }
        i++;
    }while(1);
    fclose(fp);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char ch[]={'\0'};` is not an unlimited size array. You've to allocate some memory for it, like `char ch[1024]={'\0'};`. Otherwise, it is the same as `char ch[1]={'\0'};`. And avoid using `gets`. Use `fgets` instead.

Comment: and you need reset `i` and check word length > 4.

Comment: And your `else if(ch[i]=='\n')` should be `if (ch[i]=='\n' || ch[i]==' ')`, since you're checking for every word. Unless you're talking about line. Since your loop already breaks at `EOF`, `else if` is not necessary anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following snippet. With this code you need to know **Maximum length of line**. This code prints 5th character on each line on **each word if its length is 5 or more.**. Hope this work for you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LINE 1000

int main()
{

    char fname[30];
    char myCurLine[MAX_LINE + 1];
    char myCurWord[MAX_LINE + 1];
    int index,loop; 
    FILE *fp;

    printf("enter file name with path\n");
    gets(fname);
    fp=fopen(fname,"r");
    if(fp==0)
       printf("file doesnot exist\n");
    else
    {
        printf("File read successfully\n");
        do
        {       
            if(fgets(myCurLine,MAX_LINE,fp) != NULL)
            {               
                index = 0;
                for(loop = 0;loop < MAX_LINE; loop++)
                {
                    myCurWord[index] = myCurLine[loop];
                    index++;

                    if((myCurLine[loop] == ' ') || (myCurLine[loop] == '\n'))
                    {
                        myCurWord[index] = '\0';                                            
                        index = 0;
                        if(strlen(myCurWord) > 4)
                        {
                            putchar(myCurWord[4]);
                        }
                        index = 0;

                        if(myCurLine[loop] == '\n')
                            break;
                    }                   
                }
            }

            if(feof(fp))
            {               
                break;
            }                           
        }while(1);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> *I wanted to find the 5th letter from every word*

That's not something your code is doing now. It is wrong for various reasons, like

- `char ch[]={'\0'};` is an array with length 1. with unbound `ch[i]`, you're overrunning the allocated memory creating  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).
- `gets()` is very dangerous, it can cause buffer overflow.
- `getc()` reads *character-by-character*, not word-by-word, so you need to take care of space character (`' '`) as a delimiter also.

etc.

My suggestion, rewrite your code using the following algorithm.

1. Allocate a buffer long enough to hold a complete *line* from the file.
2. Open the file, check for success.
3. Read a whole line to the buffer using [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets)

   3.1. If `fgets()` return NULL, you've *most probably* reached the end of file. End.

   3.2. Otherwise, continue to next step.
4. Tokenize the *line* using [`strtok()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok), using space `' '` as the delimiter. Check the returned token against NULL.

   4.1. if token is NULL, go to step 3.

   4.2. if token is not NULL, proceeded to next step .
5. Check [`strlen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen) of the returned token (which is the *word*). if it is more than `4`, print the *index* 4 of the token. (Remember, array index in `c` is `0` based).
6. Continue to step 4.

Answer (score 1):

**I edited your code because of these reasons:**

- You don't need to use `char` array at all, since you're only checking for letters and you can count the letters in every word of the file (which can be checked using spaces) and print when your count reaches `4` (since we start at `0`).
- Since `gets()` has no overflow protection, `fgets()` is more preferred.

  `fgets(fname, sizeof(fname), stdin);`
- Another point is you can simplify your `do-while` loop into one `while` loop with the condition of breaking if reaching `EOF`, since your `do-while` is simply an infinite loop (with condition defined as `true` or `1`) that breaks at `EOF` (which is checked in a separate `if` inside the infinite `do-while`).

  `while (!feof)`
- An alternative to `char` array is to loop until a space `' '` or newline `'\n'` is found.
- I also removed the `else` from `if (fp==0)` to avoid too many indents.
- I also added `ctype.h` to check if the 5th letter is really a letter using `isalpha()`.

> **This is how the word's 5th letter search works:**
>
> 1. Loop (**outer loop**) until end-of-file (`EOF`).
> 2. In each iteration of **outer loop**, loop (***inner loop***) until a space `' '` or newline `'\n'` is found.
>
>    - If the counter in ***inner loop*** reaches `4` (which means 5th letter is reached),
>
>      - print the current letter,
>      - reset counter to zero,
>      - then break the ***inner loop***.

**Applying those edits to your code,**

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<conio.h>
 #include<ctype.h>

 int main(void){
      char fname[30];

      char ch; // changed from array to single char
      int i=0;
      FILE *fp;

      printf("enter file name with path\n");
      fgets(fname, sizeof(fname), stdin); // changed from gets()

      // removes the \n from the input, or else the file won't be located
      // I never encountered a file with newlines in its name.
      strtok(fname, "\n");

      fp=fopen(fname,"r");

      // if file open failed,
      // it tells the user that file doesn't exits,
      // then ends the program
      if (!fp) {
           printf("file does not exist\n");
           return -1;
      }

      // loops until end-of-file
      while (!feof(fp))

           // loops until space or newline or when 5th letter is found
           for (i = 0; (ch=getc(fp)) != ' ' && ch != '\n'; i++)

                // if 5th character is reached and it is a letter
                if (i == 4 && isalpha(ch)) {
                     putc(ch ,stdout);

                     // resets letter counter, ends the loop
                     i = 0;
                     break;
                }


      fclose(fp);
      return 0;
 }
```

***Note:** Words with less than 5 letters will not be included in the output, but you can specify a character or number to indicate that a word has less than 5 letters. (such as `0`, `-1`)

sample **`read.txt`**:

> ```
> reading write love
> coder heart
> stack overflow
> ```

output:

```
enter file name with path
read.txt
iertkf
```